# Symfony2 - app.user not synced with database

Tags: php, symfony, session, fosuserbundle

I have a page called lobby in which a user can accept a friend request. Accepting a friend request leads to this action :

```
public function acceptFriendRequestAction($requestId)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();

    // Here $user is modified and changes are saved in database

    return $this->redirect('ACAppBundle:Lobby:index');
}
```

A template is rendered, using app.user to show friends and requests.
However, changes in the database are not taken into account. User object is the same as it was before acceptFriendRequestAction. When page is refreshed, app.user is synced with database.

Why do I need to refresh the page to see changes in the database ?
How to set app.user as updated user ?

When I use forward instead of redirect it works but I don't want to use this because forward doesn't change the URL.

I also noticed that sometimes a class named Proxies/.../User is used instead of User. Could that have something to do with my problem ?
Thank you for helping, I've been stuck on this for days...

Comment: Have you tried flushing after the remove but before the next persist?

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I've tried this, however, the request is effectively removed after the 'remove'. I've checked this by retrieving the user from the database using its id ('$this->getUser->getId()) just before redirection. Request is removed. In the index action it is not the case though.

Comment: Can you show the relations between the 2 models (the get/set from the request and the add/remove/get from the user)?

Comment: Sure, I edited my question. Getters/setters are those written automatically by symfony

Comment: It might be a problem with session though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that i've found the solution :

I replaced :

```
return $this->redirect('ACAppBundle:Lobby:index');
```

with

```
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('ac_app_lobby'));
```

Now after redirection, new friend is shown without needing to reload page.

I don't understand what's the difference between the two lines though. Can someone explain that?

Answer (score 1):

You need add cascade options for your relations in Friendship class for $request field

More info http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations

Comment: I added cascade remove to the user class :  `code` @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AC\FriendBundle\Entity\FriendRequest", mappedBy="receiver", cascade={"remove"})
     */
 protected $pendingRequests;     No result... And in friendship class, $request field has cascade remove and persist

Comment: Try add cascade persist in Friendship entity for $request field

Comment: For $pendingRequests  not need cascade remove...  Cascade remove mean remove FriendRequest entities when user removed

Comment: Right, I thought it only removed the relationship between the two entities. If $request object already exists, what will cascade persist do when a Friendship object is created and $request is linked to this Friendship?

Comment: Updated $request also will be flushed. 
Instead you can just add $em->persist($request); before flush

Answer (score 0):

You aren't updating the actual relationship when you are removing the friendship request. When you do the `removeElement` you are just removing it in memory until you set the `sender` or `receiver` to null.

You can do this by hand like..

```
$user->removePendingRequest($request);
$request->setSender(null);
// or $request->setReceiver(null);
```

Or you can add it to the add/remove to do it automatically like..

```
public function removeFriendship(FriendshipInterface $friendship)
{
    if ($this->friendships->contains($friendships)) {
        $this->friendships->removeElement($friendships);
        $friendship->setSender(null);
        // or $friendship->setReceiver(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: As you can see in the acceptFriendRequest action, that's what I did :   $request->setReceiver(null);

Comment: I've had this issue though. Putting it directly in the remove function is a good idea ! Note that when page is refreshed, friend request is no more displayed. As if refreshing the page triggers a new call to the database to retrieve the updated user object. Thanks for your help.